# How to convert a list of variable numbers of "couples" to a two column dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I generate a dataframe from the coauthors list of lists which has two columns (auth1 and auth2)
with one row for each couple?

```
coauthors = []
coauthors.append((("f","g"),("f","h"),("g","h"))) # combinations of f,g,h
coauthors.append((("i","j"),("i","k"),("i","l"),("j","k"),("j","l"),("l","k"))) # combinations of i,j,k,l
coauthors.append((("a","b"))) # combinations of a,b
for s in coauthors:
   print(*s)
```

Side question: Why is the last line printed by the above for not ('a','b') but rather a b ?

Comment: To answer the last question first, the asterisk tells a function to unpack the iterable it receives

Comment: For your main question, what have you tried so far? What didn't work? What is a sample of your preferred output? Please see the following link on creating a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell if you have those values, or hardcoded the combiations. But this can be much easier if you use `itertools`. Create a lists of lists, with each sublist being the groupings of authors you want to create a pairing from, then use chain and combination to get all of your pairings into a `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations, chain
groups = [['f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], ['a', 'b']]

pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable([combinations(x, 2) for x in groups]),
             columns=['auth1', 'auth2'])
```

#### Output:

```
  auth1 auth2
0     f     g
1     f     h
2     g     h
3     i     j
4     i     k
5     i     l
6     j     k
7     j     l
8     k     l
9     a     b
```

---

If you also need to add a unique `ID` for each group, you can concat a bunch of smaller `DataFrames`:

```
pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['auth1', 'auth2']).assign(id=gid) 
        for data,gid in zip([combinations(x, 2) for x in groups], range(len(groups)))
], ignore_index=True)

  auth1 auth2  id
0     f     g   0
1     f     h   0
2     g     h   0
3     i     j   1
4     i     k   1
5     i     l   1
6     j     k   1
7     j     l   1
8     k     l   1
9     a     b   2
```

Alternatively, you can unpack stuff into a list of 3 element lists and call `pd.DataFrame` once:

```
pd.DataFrame([[*z, gid] for data,gid in zip([combinations(x, 2) for x in groups], range(len(groups))) for z in data],
              columns=['auth1', 'auth2', 'id'])
```

Comment: In effect I am generating those tuples with the itertools.combinations function already. Will try to study/understand the chain function which I do not know about. As I asked under the reply from @thesilkworm would this chain verb also help me add another variable (uid) to each dataframe row? Thank you very much.

Comment: @RobertAlexander chain just allows you to move through a bunch of itertables. In this case, we take the list of iterable combinations and essentially get a single list of all tuples pairs.

Comment: Thank you. I believe I understand now. And how would you be able to add a third column to the dataframe containing a unique id value for each of those 3 groups?

Comment: @RobertAlexander, I added one way, there are likely others. I assign a counter starting at 0 to each `DataFrame` which represents the unique ID, and then concatenate each DataFrame at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `extend` rather than `append` to construct your original list:

```
coauthors = []
coauthors.extend((("f","g"),("f","h"),("g","h"))) # combinations of f,g,h
coauthors.extend((("i","j"),("i","k"),("i","l"),("j","k"),("j","l"),("l","k"))) # combinations of i,j,k,l
coauthors.extend((("a","b"),)) # combinations of a,b
```

This has the effect of extending the original list with elements of the iterable passed, rather than appending the passed iterable as a single new element of the original list.

Also notice that I added an extra comma to your last line above (to fix the issue in your side question). This is to tell Python that you would like to pass to `extend` a tuple of tuples (outer tuple contains only one tuple). Without this additional comma, the outer brackets are ignored and Python thinks you are only passing the tuple `('a', 'b')`.

This gives a list of 10 tuples of length 2, rather than the nested structure generated by using `append`. From here, creating the DataFrame is easy:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(coauthors, columns=['auth1', 'auth2'])
```

Giving:

```
  auth1 auth2
0     f     g
1     f     h
2     g     h
3     i     j
4     i     k
5     i     l
6     j     k
7     j     l
8     l     k
9     a     b
```

Comment: I have learned a lot from reading your answer thrice :) Those tuples are generated by the itertools.combination function. Every time I invoke it I also have a UID variable. How would I modify your code so that I store UID, author1, author2 triples for each dataframe row? Thank you a bunch.